# Writing, Deleting and Searching Specific Data In Java

Tags: java, bufferedreader, bufferedwriter

I just started using Java last 2 months ago so I am not good enough in using FILE I/O. I’m new here in Stackoverflow and this is my first post and I hope someone could help me solve my problem. By the way, I am making an INVENTORY SYSTEM that can “WRITE”,  “DELETE” items, price, etc. in a text file using `JOptionPane.showInputDialog`, and can also allow user to “SEARCH” the selected item and display an appropriate output in `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog`. So far, I am done in writing items, and other information in a text file. My problem now is UPDATING the price, DELETE and SEARCHING it.

This is the sample input and output:

```
//sample data in text file                                                                
ITEM NAME: PAPER                                                                          
QUANTITY: 15                                                                         
ORIGINAL PRICE: P10.00                                                                     
SRP PRICE: P11.00                                                                            

ITEM NAME: BALLPEN                                                                          
QUANTITY: 20                                                                         
ORIGINAL PRICE: P15.00                                                                     
SRP PRICE: P16.00                                                                          

//DELETE and SEARCH sample input and output:

IF USER WANT TO DELETE                                                                     
Example:                                                                                  
ITEM YOU WANT TO DELETE: PAPER                                                            
//all information of Item paper in the text file will be deleted

IF USER WANT TO SEARCH                                                                        
Example:                                                                                  
ITEM YOU WANT TO SEARCH: BALLPEN                                                            
Output In JOptionPane:                                                                          
ITEM NAME: BALLPEN                                                                            
//the quantity, original and srp price will be displayed
```

Thanks in advance :-)

This is my code for writing data in a text file
    public class DataInventory {

```
public void AddNewItem (String itemName, String qntity, String costPrice, String sellPrice) throws IOException{

    BufferedWriter writeOnFile = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File(
            "Storage.txt"), true));

    double cnvrtCostPrice = Double.parseDouble(costPrice);
    double cnvrtSellPrice = Double.parseDouble(sellPrice);


    for (int i = 0; i < invStorage.length; i++){


        if (invStorage[i] == null){

            invStorage[i] = itemName;

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  qntity + " " + itemName.toUpperCase() 
                    + " SUCCESSFULLY ADDED TO INVENTORY","Done", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);


            writeOnFile.write("ITEM NAME: " + itemName.toUpperCase() + "\n");
            writeOnFile.write("QUANTITY: " + qntity + "\n");
            writeOnFile.write("ORIGINAL PRICE: P" + String.format("%.2f", cnvrtCostPrice) + "\n");
            writeOnFile.write("SRP PRICE: P" + String.format("%.2f", cnvrtSellPrice) + "\n\n");
            writeOnFile.write("___________________________________________\n\n");
            writeOnFile.close();

            return;
        }
   }
  }
private static String invStorage[] = new String [1000];
}
```

Comment: And your problem is...

Comment: You already have one problem: you don't specify the encoding with which you write the file

Comment: My code above is a method for writing the "name of item", "quantity", "original price" and "srp price" in my text file named "Storage.txt". So my problem is how to delete or search specific item. If I'm going to delete that item, it should be remove in the text file including its information and if i'm going to search it, it should be displayed (including its information) in a message dialog box. I have given a sample input and output above. I hope you can help me.